# Calculation of inner product of star operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the 113 page of Jost's *RIEMANNIAN GEOMETRY AND GEOMETRIC ANALYSIS*. In 3.3.49 , why there is not term with $\Gamma_{kl}^j\Gamma_{mn}^r$ ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last term in (3.3.49) has uncontracted indices $k$ and $l$, and one extra index $m$, so there is obviously a typo in it. The penultimate term has a similar problem.

Comment: Missing  term of $\Gamma_{kl}^j\Gamma_{mn}^r$ is a typo ?

Comment: @lanse7pty yes, you need to carefully check the calculation, which is just a simple expansion of parentheses and subsequent simplification. These things frequently happen when typesetting such expressions... Another option would be to use a computer algebra system of your choice :)